# sqlalchemy.exc.ResourceClosedError: This result object does not return rows. It has been closed automatically

Tags: mysql, python-2.7, pandas

```
sql='delete a from  sample a, TEMPLATE b  where a.emailid=b.emailid '

df=psql.read_sql_query(sql,con=engine)

print df.head()
```

how do i delete common rows using pandas without reading the table or csv.
Kinldy please suggest me a best way....as reading of table is taking lot of time i used"pd.read_sql_table"

Comment: Why are you executing sql with read_Sql? Do you want to delete and then read the remaining rows or just want to delete the rows?

Answer (score 1):

Pandas is using sqlalchemy under the hood, simply run your query using the engine.

```
with engine.begin() as conn:
    conn.execute(sql)
    # safety checks go here, once the end of the with clause is reached the trans is committed.
```